# Is there any way to be more efficient when taking values from a spreasheet if they contain certain value?

Tags: google-apps-script

I´m new at this and I´m trying to copy and paste certain rows (every row that contains the value "Buenos días" in the column C) from spreadsheet 1 (CSV) into spreadsheet 2 (buenosDias). It takes too much time to the script to totally run and I cannot find a way to be more efficient.Is there any way to be more efficient? This is the code I have come up with:

```
function buenosDias() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ur1Y7KoPONxPiFBMdGR4UfJW4GfyLy4MDxTEk30mg8w/edit#gid=0"); var sheets = ss.getSheets();
     var buenosDias = ss.getSheetByName("Buenos días");   var range = buenosDias.getDataRange().getValues();   var CSV = ss.getSheetByName("CSV");
     var lastRowA = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVA = CSV.getRange(1, 1, lastRowA).getValues();

  var lastRowB = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVB = CSV.getRange(1, 2, lastRowB).getValues();
     var lastRowC = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVC = CSV.getRange(1, 3, lastRowC).getValues();

  var lastRowD = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVD = CSV.getRange(1, 4, lastRowD).getValues();
     var lastRowE = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVE = CSV.getRange(1, 5, lastRowE).getValues();

  var lastRowF = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVF = CSV.getRange(1, 6, lastRowF).getValues();
     var lastRowG = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVG = CSV.getRange(1, 7, lastRowG).getValues();

  var lastRowH = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVH = CSV.getRange(1, 8, lastRowH).getValues();
     var lastRowI = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVI = CSV.getRange(1, 9, lastRowI).getValues();

  var lastRowJ = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVJ = CSV.getRange(1, 10, lastRowJ).getValues();
     var lastRowK = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVK = CSV.getRange(1, 11, lastRowK).getValues();

  var lastRowL = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVL = CSV.getRange(1, 12, lastRowL).getValues();
     var lastRowM = CSV.getLastRow();   var CSVM = CSV.getRange(1, 13, lastRowM).getValues();

     for (var i = 1;i < CSVA.length; i++) {

    var lastRow0 = buenosDias.getLastRow();
    var RowToComplete = lastRow0;

    if (CSVC[i] == "Buenos días") {

      buenosDias.getRange(RowToComplete+1, 1).setValue(CSVA[i]).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      buenosDias.getRange(RowToComplete+1, 2).setValue(CSVF[i]).setNumberFormat("0").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      buenosDias.getRange(RowToComplete+1, 3).setValue(CSVH[i]).setNumberFormat("0").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      buenosDias.getRange(RowToComplete+1, 4).setValue(CSVH[i]/CSVF[i]).setNumberFormat("00.00%").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      buenosDias.getRange(RowToComplete+1, 5).setValue(CSVJ[i]).setNumberFormat("0").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      buenosDias.getRange(RowToComplete+1, 6).setValue(CSVJ[i]/CSVF[i]).setNumberFormat("00.00%").setHorizontalAlignment("center");

    }
       } }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, use `setValues` to batch-write and figure out how to reduce the number of times you need to call `getLastRow()`. Review the "Apps Script best practices" guide in the official documentation for examples, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) so you don't need to get the last Row of the Sheet, as it will add the values at the end of the Sheet.

Also, I made a single `for` loop to iterate over the Column C, looking for the string "Buenos dias". If it coincides, then appends that row to the CSV Sheet. Don't forget to change the `numberofColumns` to the actual number of Columns you want to copy from each row from Column A.

From the `setHorizontalAlignment` loop you made at the end I guess you want to center all the data of the CSV Sheet. It's easier to set it for all the [Data Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) instead of looping over all the rows.

```
function buenosDias() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ur1Y7KoPONxPiFBMdGR4UfJW4GfyLy4MDxTEk30mg8w/edit#gid=0"); 
  var buenosDias = ss.getSheetByName("Buenos días");   
  var CSV = ss.getSheetByName("CSV");

  var range = CSV.getRange("C1:C").getValues(); //Range goes from C1 to the last C with values   

  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){

    if (range[i][0] == "Buenos días"){

      CSV.appendRow(buenosDias.getRange((i+1), 1, numberofColumns).getValues());

    }

  }
  CSV.getDataRange().setHorizontalAlignment('center');

}
```